# Xamarin SignalR Android System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, xamarin.android

This is my first attempt at a Xamarin Android project. I have created a SignalR server in a console application and this is working fine. I am trying to create a Xamarin Android project in Visual Studio that can use SignalR to connect to my server. I have used nuget to add

```
Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client
```

and

```
Newtonsoft.Json
```

When I try to build the project I am getting tthis error.

```
 Error      Exception while loading assemblies:            System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assemblySystem.Net.Http.Extensions, Version=1.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,    PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
```

I can't find anything on Nuget called

```
System.Net.Http.Extensions.dll
```

Comment: It is the system file.You can't find it on NuGet.Try Add Reference then Assemblies.You will get mentioned dll inside Assemblies tab or try to install `System.Net.Http` from NuGet.

Comment: There is no System.Net.Http.Extensions under assemblies tab and I already have a reference to System.Net.http

Comment: Then Follow this link : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/36281/system-net-http-extensions-cannot-be-found-although-it-is-not-used. You will find the solution

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client -- Is this the correct version of signalr nuget to use?

Comment: Yes It is the correct version to use

Comment: Then there is a problem - There is no user code just the template and it wont build.

Comment: Will revert back to you when I found any solution.

Comment: same problem here

Comment: i am facing this problem too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried this and it works with **VisualStudio 2015**

I downloaded the complete package from **Xamarin** account which is just one step to create.

And then go to the [signalR package for Xamarin](https://components.xamarin.com/view/signalr), and download the complete package.
the go for the following path

```
yourdownlodfolder\signalr-2.1.2.2\signalr-2.1.2.2\lib\android
```

you will find something like [image: this]

Include it in your **bin** folder. and than **add refenrences** *manually* .
and you are done. Now follow the steps mentioned in the above link to create **HubProxy**

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem.
After install the SignalR Client on my Xamarin Forms PCL application, the Android app  breaks on build.

I opened a issue on the github. Posted a simple repo app.
The SignalR is the major functionality, so I'm pretty much stuck.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3775

Comment: Would appreciate if you let me know of a resolution. No way to go forward with this.

Comment: I have no idea on why...
I was using Visual Studio 2015, I tried to install the SIgnalR packages using the Visual Studio 2013 and works!!!??!!
Maybe is the nuget version version?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, to solve the problem i installed the nuget Microsoft.Net.Http and rebuild de project.